# How to input truth table and generate corresponding logical expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation, logic

I want to input truth table and generate the corresponding logical expression.

For example, I have truth table:

```
a         b     
True    True    
True    False   
False   True    
False   False
```

OR

```
a       b       
1       1
1       0
0       1
0       0
```

How can I input these truth tables and generate (get output) logical expression in the format like $ a\vee b $? The input of table in **mathematica code** is very good. The output format with symbols in logical expression is preferable. But if there is no way to get in the output logical expression with symbols and there is only the way to get output in **mathematica code** that will be ok too.

Can you please give me the complete working example of the code that can do that?

Comment: BooleanConvert applied to a BooleanFunction generated by your truth table.  See examples in the docs under each command.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can you please give me the complete working code for some simple truth table conversion to logical expression?

Comment: Please show us input examples and desired results.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and **Mathematica code** attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O).By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers.

Comment: I think it needs **mathematica code** for the formatted input and output. I assume you are not expecting a plain text input and $\LaTeX$ output. Are you?

Comment: @rhermans **Mathematica code** for input is very good. But the output is better in math symbols (latex-like). I thought that if I can input logical expressions by inserting latex-like math symbols (from special characters GUI) for logical expressions, there also should be a way to output logical expressions in that format. So that format of the output is preferable. But if there is no way of that kind of output and it is only possible to output in **mathematica code** then this way is ok too.

Comment: If that is the case, please [edit] your question and *make it explicit in the question*, otherwise you are asking us to speculate.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you. Done. Any other way I can improve my question?

Comment: You can improve your question by **trying** something. Read the docs on `BooleanFunction` and `BooleanConvert`, write some code, and, if it doesn't work, show us what didn't work.

Comment: @JohnDoty I have read about that functions after the first comment but did not understand how to do what I need. That is why I am asking.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot copy the code from the [5th example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanFunction.html#316626102) in the docs for `BooleanFunction`, but you would like me to do it for you?  (You can also use the search feature (cmd-F on Mac) to search the doc page for `BooleanConvert`, "table", etc., to find related examples.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 1. This code gives me answer in mathematica code right? `BooleanFunction[{{False, False} -> False, {False, True} -> 
   True, {True, False} -> True, {True, True} -> True}, {a, b}]`. 2. Is the experrsion in output most simplified form or I need to aditionally simplify expression? 3. Now to convert mathematica code that I recived from `BooleanFunction` to symbolic form I need to use `BooleanConvert`, is it right?

Comment: @MichaelE2 2. I use `BooleanMinimize[a||b]` to simplify the logical expression, is it the right way? 4. I could not find the way to convert `a||b` to  $ a\vee b $ . I looked at `BooleanConvert` but have not found the way to do that. How can I do it?